# Insufficient permissions error when inserting a new Google analytics view

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

```
$KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/service-account-credentials.json';

// Create and configure a new client object.
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
$client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics']);
$analytics = new \Google_Service_Analytics($client);

// Construct the body of the request and set its properties.
$profile = new \Google_Service_Analytics_Profile();
$profile->setName('View name');

$analytics->management_profiles->insert('123425914', 'UA-2344718-15', $profile);
```

I try to insert view on GA App but API return `insufficient permissions error`.

When I had tried to get data if I enter the wrong `$VIEW_ID` then the same error is printed.

I had enter those parms in insert method

1. existing VIEW_ID - the same error occurred if enter none existed VIEW_ID.
2. Second param is existed APP_ID.

Do you see some mistake here? I double check permissions on GA dashboard and everything seems to be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. either the user you are authenticating with does not have admin permissions on the Google Analytics account.
2. You have not received beta access to the write methods on the Management API.

[Views (Profiles): insert](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles/insert)

> Write operations in the Management API (e.g. create, update, delete, patch) for Web Property, View (Profile), and Goal resources are currently available as a developer preview in limited beta. If you're interested in using these features, [request access to the beta](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf01NWo9R-SOHLKDUH0U4gWHNDBIY-gEI-zqBMG1Hyh3_hHZw/viewform).